# Django: How to add another form to my homepage when the homepage already has a template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

On my homepage(http://127.0.0.1:8000/) I created a template and its function in views.py and the URL of the homepage directs to it, however, there is a form that I want also to show on the homepage.

views.py:

```
def index(request):
template = loader.get_template('tracker/index.html')
hours_grouped_project = 
LogHours.objects.all().order_by('proj_assignment__project__name', 'day')

context = {
    'hours_grouped_project':hours_grouped_project,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))

def form(request):
    if request.method== 'POST':
    form = LogHoursForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        day = form.cleaned_data['day']
        hours = form.cleaned_data['hours']
        developer = form.cleaned_data['developer']
        project = form.cleaned_data['project']
        proj_assignment=ProjectAssignment.objects.create(
                        developer=developer,project=project)
        LogHours.objects.create(day=day,hours=hours, 
                                proj_assignment= proj_assignment)
    else:
       form = LogHoursForm()

    return render(request, 'tracker/form.html',{'form': form})
```

the index is for the template displayed on the homepage, and the form is for the form.py.

form.py

```
class LogHoursForm(forms.Form):
day = forms.DateField()
hours = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
developer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Developer.objects.all())
project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all())
```

and here is the URL: urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),]

the form.html is

```
<h1> LogHours Form</h1>
<hr>

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the index.html:

```
<ul>
    <b>Logged hours grouped by project:</b>
{% for obj in hours_grouped_project %}
<li>
    {% ifchanged obj.proj_assignment %}
    <b>Project name:</b>
    {{obj.proj_assignment|linebreaks}}
    {% endifchanged %}
    <i>Sorted Date: </i>
    {{obj}}
</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

Comment: Please insert your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `index(request):`

```
def index(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form(request)
    else:
        template = loader.get_template('tracker/index.html')
        hours_grouped_project = LogHours.objects.all().order_by('proj_assignment__project__name', 'day')

        form = LogHoursForm()

        context = {
            'hours_grouped_project': hours_grouped_project,
            'form': form,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Then, you can render the form from your `index.html` like this.

```
...
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
<input type="submit">
...
```

Comment: it shows the data from index.html only. it didn't show the form... and in that way the views.form function is not called anywhere?

Comment: I've edited the code. I hope this will work.

Comment: Is there any error message or something? Did you correctly add the form snippet in index.html?

Comment: I have a question if I added this ...
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
<input type="submit">
... to the index.html then what is the point of form.html?

Comment: `form.html` renders your form. I just wrote the part which is necessary to render the form. You can use `form.html` inside your `index.html` using `include()` / `extends()` function

Comment: Thank you, it worked! but I had to remove the if and else cond bec there was an error that the function must return sth like that.